# how to open two different intent action using single button in android

Tags: android

hello everyone im making an android app where i have to open two different activities from same button  based on some condition.I use if else statement in btn.setOnClickListener but it didn't work.
My code is

```
    getSell = p.getStringExtra("buy");
    l1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (getSell.equals("buy")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(fanfBook.this, Main.class);

                startActivity(i);

            }
            else{

               Intent i = new Intent(fanfBook.this, Main1.class);

                startActivity(i);


            }
        }
    });


}
```

Somebody plz help me....

Comment: "but it didn't work" -- please explain **in detail** what "it didn't work" means. In your code, in one case, you are starting an activity; in the other case, you are finishing the current activity.

Comment: the if else condition are not working on onClick() method

Comment: @NickyManali elaborate the phrase "not working"

Comment: hmm the problem is that i can use only one click event in li.setOnclickListener but i want to use two condition on the basis of if else satement.but when im using it it showing error that virtual method or null point projection of if condition

Comment: what do you want to do exactly in "else" part?

Comment: ok i get it that u didnt get the queation it doesn't matter what i want to open in else condition lets take i want to open another activity in else.again it giving the same error

Comment: @NickyManali: what is the error?

Comment: post the error otherwise its hard to undertsand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access local variable inside anonymous class (new View.OnClickListener()) you need to declare the variables as members of outer class. I.e.

```
class MainActivity{
  public String getSell;

  public void OnCreate(){
    ...
    getSell = ...;

    l1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (MainActivity.this.getSell.equals("buy")){
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: srry i didn't understand the answer.

Comment: well you have changed the code so it doesn't apply anymore